# Maps is rendering a bit too slow when zoom in/out

Tags: android, google-maps

I need some help to improve the performance of my algorithm, I'm struggling for days and can't find a good solution.

**Goal**: My app need to show a marker for each airport in the world (~1k markers), and each marker must show the airport name.

**What I did:** For the marker, I created an RelativeLayout with the Icon and a TextView to populate the name of aiport.
Also, I wrote a class "AirportCluster" extending **DefaultClusterRenderer** and inside the overrode method **onBeforeClusterItemRendered** I just cast the layout to Bitmap so it can be rendered on the map

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(AirportItem airportItem, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

     RelativeLayout customLayoutMarker = (RelativeLayout) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_airport_marker,null);

     String tAirportName = airportItem.getAirport().getAirportName().toLowerCase();
     tAirportName = Character.toUpperCase(tAirportName.charAt(0)) + tAirportName.substring(1);

     TextView textLabelAirportMarker = (TextView) customLayoutMarker.findViewById(R.id.label_text_airport_marker);
     textLabelAirportMarker.setText(tAirportName);

     customLayoutMarker.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     customLayoutMarker.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
     customLayoutMarker.layout(0,0, customLayoutMarker.getMeasuredWidth(), customLayoutMarker.getMeasuredHeight());
     customLayoutMarker.buildDrawingCache(true);

    Bitmap flagBitmap;
    if ( mMemoryCache.get(tAirportName) == null){
        flagBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(customLayoutMarker.getDrawingCache());
        mMemoryCache.put(tAirportName,flagBitmap);
     }else{
        flagBitmap = mMemoryCache.get(tAirportName);
    }

     BitmapDescriptor markerAirportWithText = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(flagBitmap);
     markerOptions.icon(markerAirportWithText);
    //markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport_marker));
}
```

As we can see in the code, I'm trying to cache it on the memory as well, but this is not working that good.
All the markers are being added on the method **onMapReady** inside a loop for each airport in the list

```
for (Airport temp : fixedAirports) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(temp.getCityLat(), temp.getCityLng());
        // create marker
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker in" + temp.getCityName());

        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport_marker));

        AirportItem offsetItem = new AirportItem(temp.getCityLat(), temp.getCityLng());
        offsetItem.setAirport(temp);
        mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
    }
```

**Issue**: I also have a custom image for clustered airports, and when i try to zoom in/out sometimes it take to much to the clustered icon dismiss and show the marker item for an airport, sometimes the icon of the item even overlaps the clustered one, just like on the images below.

[image: clustered airports markers]
[image: zomming out clustered airports markers]

**What I have to do to these animations (changing from clustered icon from single markers) be more fast and smooth??**

Comment: I have similar issues and I'm using the profiler to check where the main thread blocks on slow operations. As example now I use addItems instead of addItem for the cluster managers and I use a cached BitmapDescriptor for my placeholder. You find all that when you use the Android Studio profiler and move the map around!

Answer (score 0):

Prepare `BitmapDescriptor`s first in background (i.e. Coroutines `viewModelScope` or another thread or asynctask or Rxjava), then load them to ui. Dont draw anything inside your `ClusterRenderer` class. Doing so helped me a bit.